# What is this poster in the background?

Tags: props, cisco-pike

I was watching the movie *Cisco Pike* and I was very interested in this creepy-looking bearded man on the poster / tapestry in the background.

It's shown in the scene when Cisco and his friend go to Merna's house. The location of the poster should be Merna's bedroom.

The image comes on screen at 94.24, which is the time of this still.

I threw this screenshot into google reverse-image search and nothing came up.

I just want to identify what this poster is of? Is it a band? A cult leader? Something creepy?

[image: cisco pike]

Comment: Whenever I see pictures of bushy-haired beared men in this form, then find the question is about a cult leader or creepy, I always think of [Rasputin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rasputin_near_1914.jpg).

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's Charles Manson, convicted in 1971, the year before this movie came out. I can't find that exact likeness however, so no answer until then.

Comment: Well, no luck. This is a 1972 "counter-culture" movie, so that could be any image from Christ, to Manson, Maharishi Yogi, even Kristoferson's good friend Willie Nelson. We'll probably not know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I've got this,
It's a poster called: Musten Baba
(poster work on paper)

I think it's a guru named Musten Baba; it's from 1968. It was produced by a company called Berkeley Bonaparte.

I think it might have been a poster used by Frank Zappa ([source](http://auctions.concertpostergallery.com/musten-baba-black-and-white-print-pae--graded-mint-lot1170.aspx))

[additional source](http://collections.museumca.org/?q=collection-item/2010541278)

[image: Image of the poster]

Comment: How did you get this to this answer? Very curious!

Comment: @ThomasReggi I cropped a screen capture so that it was just the image of the face and did a google image search, then followed the links until I had the name of the poster and the name of the artist. Unfortunately I couldn't uncover the name of the artist, just the company that originally made the poster. My guess is that the artist is [Rick Griffin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_Griffin) but since I can't prove it I didn't add that into the answer.

Comment: Interesting. I tried the same thing and no results came up for the image search. Thanks again!